# WPF VB.NET : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I just wanted to take a listbox value to existing labels on different forms. an error on this code :

```
keyword.Content = w_list.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
```

**error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

can anybody help me?

Comment: Either `keyword` or `w_list` or `ListBox1` or `SelectedItem` is `Nothing`, that's what the error message tells you. Only you can debug it.

Comment: i put the item listbox on the form w_list, I load the listbox item from notepad.
the problem is an error in the form p_list, where the label that I used to read the value of the items in the form w_list an error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

line error : line label.Content = w_list.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString